# Modify multiple columns value based on specific column values in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, centos7

I have a file that has the following data

```
"col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6"
"CACR","0","SO2","50","6","2.0"
"FF","15","CO2","20","4","3"
"CACR","25","NOx","30","10",        
"CACR","50","CO","40","5","0"
```

I want to find every line that contains CACR  and then divide  col2,  col4, col5, and col6 values by the respective cells of col6 (ignore the divide calculation if col6 has 0 or blank cells) using Linux terminal. So, my output looks like following:

```
"col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6"
"CACR","0","SO2","25","3","1"
"CACR","25","NOX","30","10",           
"CACR","50","CO","40","5","0"
```

I am trying to use grep and awk

```sh
grep  CACR  file.csv | awk -F "," '$6 != 0; $6 == "" {$2 = $2/$6; $4= $4/$6; $5 = $5/$6; $6 = $6/$6}1'
```

But couldn't get any desired output.

Comment: you don't need ```grep``` if you're using ```awk```. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi @vgersh99 sorry for the late reply, I edited the question with what I have been trying. I tried this    grep  CACR  file.csv | awk -F "," '$6 != 0; $6 == "" {$2 = $2/$6; $4= $4/$6; $5 = $5/$6; $6 = $6/$6}1'

Comment: Do you really have so many spaces after the commas in the input data?  The double quotes are going to make life difficult — if they were absent, you can do the arithmetic, but with the double quotes, the strings (fields) do not convert to numbers so arithmetic does not work.  You will need to strip the quotes from the fields (write an Awk function to do that), and then you can do the arithmetic.  Reprinting the fields with the quotes will be a nuisance too; again, write an Awk function to help.

Comment: Hello @JonathanLeffler I don't have spaces between columns. But I will have to keep all the double quotes and commas in my output.

Comment: Please update the data in the question to remove the spaces — they're misleading.  For the rest, a `strip_quotes` function and an `add_quotes()` function should help.  I observe that your `grep` solution loses the column headings — using just `awk` means you can keep the column headings.

Comment: Hello, @JonathanLeffler Thank you for the response. I updated the data in question. I notice if I simply divide a column by a number , the output loses the comma, For example, if I do   awk -F "," '{$col5 = $col5/5}1'   the output automatically removes comma (,) only keeps " "  why is that?. How do I keep both comma and double quotes in that simple division?. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68531590/modify-multiple-columns-value-based-on-specific-column-values-in-linux#comment121144045_68531590), the primary problem is that the double quotes around the fields mean that when a field is interpreted as a number (e.g. with a division), the value is zero.  I think you need to write Awk functions to remove and reinstate the double quotes.  With those in place, it's mostly a [SMOP](https://www.acronymfinder.com/SMOP.html) — a Simple Matter of Programming.

Here's my version.  It could be written more succinctly (fewer newlines, fewer spaces), but I prefer clarity over brevity.

#### `script.awk`

```
function strip_quotes(s)
{
    gsub(/"/, "", s)
    return s
}
function add_quotes(s)
{
    return sprintf("\"%s\"", s)
}
BEGIN        { FS = "," }
NR == 1      { print; next }
$0 !~ /CACR/ { next }
$6 == "" || $6 == "\"0\"" { print; next }
        {
            div = strip_quotes($6)
            printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",
                   $1,
                   add_quotes(strip_quotes($2) / div),
                   $3,
                   add_quotes(strip_quotes($4) / div),
                   add_quotes(strip_quotes($5) / div),
                   add_quotes(strip_quotes($6) / div))
        }
```

#### `data`

```
"col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6"
"CACR","0","SO2","50","6","2.0"
"FF","15","CO2","20","4","3"
"CACR","25","NOx","30","10",
"CACR","50","CO","40","5","0"
```

#### Output

```
$ awk -f script.awk data
"col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6"
"CACR","0","SO2","25","3","1"
"CACR","25","NOx","30","10",
"CACR","50","CO","40","5","0"
$
```

#### Variant `script3.awk`

This code sets the output field separator `OFS` to comma too, and resets the values of `$2`, `$4`, `$5`, and `$6` before using `print` to print the modified `$0`.

```
function strip_quotes(s)
{
    gsub(/"/, "", s)
    return s
}
function add_quotes(s)
{
    return sprintf("\"%s\"", s)
}
BEGIN        { FS = ","; OFS = "," }
NR == 1      { print; next }
$0 !~ /CACR/ { next }
$6 == "" || $6 == "\"0\"" { print; next }
        {
            div = strip_quotes($6)
            $2 = add_quotes(strip_quotes($2) / div)
            $4 = add_quotes(strip_quotes($4) / div)
            $5 = add_quotes(strip_quotes($5) / div)
            $6 = add_quotes(strip_quotes($6) / div)
            print
        }
```

#### Data validation

Both versions of the script could be more stringent, validating that there are 5 or 6 columns (rejecting lines with more columns or fewer columns or complaining about them).  The check for the headings could insist on 6 columns.  It might be sensible to check that `div` is a non-zero number.  It might be sensible to check that each of `$2`, `$4`, `$5` and `$6` is a number.  The divisors (column 6) in the sample data are convenient; you might need to do some work if the number is not as simple, such as `7`, where the result could have many decimal places.  You'd need to decide how such numbers should be formatted (the default might be OK, or it might not).  It might also be worth checking that the data in each field matches the regex `/^"[^"]*"$/` (so each value is surrounded by double quotes).

#### Trailing white space

The rule `$6 == "" || $6 == "\"0\"" { print; next }` does not handle trailing white space very well.  It can be revised to:

```
$6 ~ /^[[:space:]]*$/ || $6 == "\"0\"" { print; next }
```

That recognizes trailing white space and treats it as zero.  It would be possible, and probably sensible, to add:

```
if (div == 0) { print; next }
```

after the assignment to `div`.  If the value found is zero, there is a problem.  It would be possible to complain too — to produce an error message diagnosing 'malformed data'.

How much of the validation and error prevention is worthwhile depends on how unruly your input data is.  If you're dealing with human-generated data, you have to deal with human's propensity for varying the rules and giving erratic or erroneous data to programs, and you probably need to handle (diagnose) unexpected inputs.  If you're dealing with machine-generated data, it is typically more uniform, and you can get away with less validation work.

Most solutions that depend on regexes have to strike a balance between working sufficiently well and breaking on erratic inputs.  The more erratic the inputs, the harder it is to devise bomb-proof (fool-proof) regexes.  As the saying goes, "if you make something [idiot-proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiot-proof), someone will just make a better idiot".

Comment: If I try to use script3.awk, I get error                                                                             awk: script.awk:18: (FILENAME=test.csv FNR=4) fatal: division by zero attempted

Comment: Which platform (o/s, version of Awk)?  I tested on a MacBook Pro running Mojave (ouch — it hurts; corporate policies).  I used both the native Awk (BSD Awk version 20070501) and GNU Awk (version 4.1.3) without problems and with the expected results.

Comment: The one thing that's different about FNR==4 is the trailing comma.  However, the test/action `$6 == "" || $6 == "\"0\"" { print; next }` should handle that.  It might be sensible to add `|| $6 == 0` to the conditions, but it shouldn't matter with the given data file.  What have you got on that line?  Trailing blanks?  CR/LF line endings?  If there is a trailing blank, I get a divide by zero error.  Trailing blanks are anathema.  We could use `$6 ~ /^[[:space:]]*$/` in place of `$6 == ""` since you probably don't have clean data.

Comment: I am using centos 7 Linux 3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64  and GNU Awk 4.0.2

Comment: While I probably could build and check with GNU Awk 4.0.2, I think the 'trailing blanks' explanation is plausible — and fixable as shown in my previous [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68531590/modify-multiple-columns-value-based-on-specific-column-values-in-linux/68548805?noredirect=1#comment121149384_68548805).  With the change to use the regex, I don't get a division by zero error because the regex matches the trailing white space and the printing is short-circuited (no divisions occur).

Comment: you are right for the 'trailing blanks' explanation. If I use $6 ~ /^[[:space:]]*$/  , I don't get error on that line. Now, the only error is occurring for the division by zero line.                   
awk: script.awk:18: (FILENAME=test.csv FNR=5) fatal: division by zero attempted

Comment: Are you using the full condition?  I intended you to use `$6 ~ /^[[:space:]]*$/ || $6 == "\"0\"" { print; next }` — if you only have the regex condition, then you will get divide-by-zero errors.  You could also use alternation in the regex: `$6 ~ /^([[:space:]]*|"0")$/` without the `||` condition.  It even avoids some backslashes, which usually makes life simpler.

Comment: Yes, I am using full condition

Comment: Hmmm: trailing (or leading) spaces on that line too?  I suppose that we might need to deal with that in the regex (as I say, it depends on how clever the data generators are): `$6 ~ /^[[:space:]]*("0")?[[:space:]]*$/` — that looks for a field consisting of zero or more white space characters, then either zero or one occurrence of `"0"` followed by zero or more white space characters (the `^` and `$` limit the match to the whole field).  As I said, regexes are usually a balance between generality and comprehensibility — this is starting to get very general but somewhat incomprehensible.

Comment: And, as I observed earlier, sloppy space management makes life hard.  You should treat trailing white space as bugs in the code (or human) that generates the input streams.  Do a Google search `define:anathema` — trailing white space is anathema!

Comment: I observe that this code doesn't try to deal with the full generality of CSV format.  It will not handle commas or double quotes embedded in fields.  It will mostly handle the absence of double quotes around fields (and asymmetric double quotes), though the output will include the double quotes when lines are processed such that the divisions are performed.

Comment: Looks like using  $6 ~ /^[[:space:]]*("0")?[[:space:]]*$/  solves the issue